# MAUI items Template are missing, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-windows

My visual studio version was 2022 17.5 Preview 1.0 , but today now it updated to 17.5 Preview 2.0. And now i can't add any MAUI item such as Content Page or others. You can see [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEKVV.png) that the option "MAUI" isn't appearing...
In the last version it was working...

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Is this a project (solution) you created with the earlier preview? If so, create a new project. Same problem? If new one works, then some internal VS incompatibility between preview versions. Delete solution's hidden `.vs` folder. Delete all `.bin` and `.obj` folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a project (solution) you created with the earlier preview?

If so, create a new project. Same problem?

If new one works, then I suspect some internal VS incompatibility between preview versions:

- Delete solution's hidden `.vs` folder.
- Delete all `.bin` and `.obj` folders.

---

No Maui "Project template" is more serious:

- Delete Visual Studio.
- Reboot PC.
- Install Visual Studio. (Windows Search should still show "Visual Studio Installer", Can install from there.)

Comment: yes, i created with the earlier preview...and now i can't create a new MAUI project, the option isn't there...

Comment: Okay. No Maui "Project template" is more serious. Delete Visual Studio. Reboot PC. Install Visual Studio. (Windows Search should still show "Visual Studio Installer", Can install from there.)

Comment: Yhup...it was the only Way...thanks brother!! 

Answer (score 1):

In command prompt run this command:

```
dotnet new install Microsoft.Maui.Templates
```

[image]